# Color box with outline but some difference

Tags: color, boxes, verbatim

```
\begin{boxedlaw}{6.4in}
\colorbox[HTML]{F8E0E0}{
\begin{minipage}[c]{380px}
\begin{center}
\begine{verbatim}

\# define       LM_ENCA     18          //Port0
\# define       LM_ENCB     17          //Port0
\# define       RM_ENCA     29          //Port0
\# define       RM_ENCB     28          //Port0
\# define       LMDir       10          //Port0
\# define       RMDir       11          //Port0

\# define       LeftTx      21          //Port1
\# define       RightTx     20          //Port1
\# define       LfrontTx    17          //Port1
\# define       RfrontTx    16          //Port1

\# define      LeftRx       13          //Port0
\# define      RightRx      12          //Port0
\# define      LfrontRx     21          //Port0
\# define      RfrontRx     22          //Port0

\# define       Buzzer      31          //Port1
\# define       ModeSel     2           //Port0

\# define       GyroOut     5           //Port0
\# define       GyroOut4X   4           //Port0

\end{verbatim}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}}
\end{boxedlaw}
```

When I use this code I keep getting an error:

```
"! Missing $ inserted."
"! Missing } inserted."
```

I have declared this new environment at the start:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}         % Extended colors
\usepackage{color}         % Color extended names

%DEFINE ENVIRONMENT BLOCK
% Riddle
\newenvironment{colbox}[3]{        % Riddle environment
  \begin{center}                   % Centering minipage
    \colorbox[HTML]{#1} {          % Set's the color of minipage
      \begin{minipage}[b]{380px}   % Starts minipage
   \textbf{#2}\\ \textit{#3}       % Set's title and starts italic for text
  \end{minipage}}                  % End minipage
}{\end{center}}                    % End Riddle environment
```

The above environment is something I have copied from a different post on this forum. However being a novice with Latex I dont know if I can use it as it is. Any help would be great.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It would be create if you could add your code as a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) which can be directly compiled by other people.

Comment: I am confused; you defined a `colbox` environment (last snippet) but you use a `boxedlaw` environment in the first snippet; where is this environment defined? Also, there's a missing `\begin{verbatim}` in the first snippet.

Comment: Sorry @GonzaloMedina. I forgot the \begin{verbatim}. What I am interested in is to get the text between the verbatim environment in a colred box with an outline around it.

Comment: @KaranThakkar: You can't use `verbatim` inside a macro argument, here the `\colorbox`. Also, when you use verbatim you should turn the `\#` into `#`, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the standard `verbatim` environment or the `\verb` command in the argument of another command. To write your verbatim material using a colored background, I would suggest you to use the [listings](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package (refer to the package documentation to see all the features it provides):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{mycolor}{HTML}{F8E0E0}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[backgroundcolor=\color{mycolor},xrightmargin=2cm]
# define       LM_ENCA     18          //Port0
# define       LM_ENCB     17          //Port0
# define       RM_ENCA     29          //Port0
# define       RM_ENCB     28          //Port0
# define       LMDir       10          //Port0
# define       RMDir       11          //Port0

# define       LeftTx      21          //Port1
# define       RightTx     20          //Port1
# define       LfrontTx    17          //Port1
# define       RfrontTx    16          //Port1

# define       LeftRx      13          //Port0
# define       RightRx     12          //Port0
# define       LfrontRx    21          //Port0
# define       RfrontRx    22          //Port0

# define       Buzzer      31          //Port1
# define       ModeSel     2           //Port0

# define       GyroOut     5           //Port0
# define       GyroOut4X   4           //Port0
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For non-verbatim material, you have the `mdframed` and `adjustbox` packages.

Comment: Yes, and for non-verbatim material there are the `mdframed` and `adjustbox` packages.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: yes; I added a little note to my answer.

Comment: Okay. I guess I got the hint.